# TCP Server Freezes On Startup

Tags: c#, tcp, client, server

So lately I have decided to get into Server/Client TCP.

I decided to start by looking at a basic server/client to get an idea for how it works.

I used this code here, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

But when I try to run the server, it halts on this and won't proceed the code for a very long time.

And once it is eventually listening for a connection, using the client will not connect to it.

Also if I attempt to shut the program while it is still stuck in this "frozen" state it will make my IDE not respond.

Any ideas?

I'm running Windows 7 on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: That's a terrible example to start with. But no TCP code should cause your IDE to stop responding. It seems unlikely that if you are using that code verbatim, that that's what's wrong with your IDE. Is it possible that there's a UAC or firewall prompt you haven't noticed? A process that opens a TCP socket for listening will require firewall permissions for access.

Comment: I'll have a search around, I've been trying some TCP Client/Server things in Java and they are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem,

It seems Avast Free Antivirus was causing all the problems. Unistalling it cleared them all up.